# Has anyone else composed for the Mahler Hammer?

Tags: composition, percussion, composers

The title pretty much sums it up:  Has anyone *else* (other than the [composer for whom it's named](https://www.gramophone.co.uk/composers/gustav-mahler-37886)) written music that incorporates the "[Mahler Hammer](https://www.wqxr.org/story/box-and-hammer-story-mahlers-6th-his-155th-birthday/)™"?

Some more links:

- [Walt Martin's blog about building a Mahler Hammer](https://waltmartin.com/building-a-mahler-hammer/)
- [Youtube video about building a Mahler Hammer](https://youtu.be/wTDqmOFlD8g)
- [Playing it during a rehearsal](https://youtu.be/iLWqTSxNDsQ)
- [Wikipedia article about Mahler's Symphony no. 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._6_(Mahler))

P.S. I sometimes think I've [asked](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54341) [too](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48884) [many](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/63372) [questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/72378) about Mahler; I suppose I'll stop now.  Lest I be accused of being a fanboy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that, according to one of your links, Mahler merely asked for "the sound of an axe falling on wood,"  that a "Mahler Box" is merely one construction that meets that need.  There are plenty of other ways to (mis)use stuff in the percussion library to create a similar sound.

I would personally have the chutzpah to tell the percussion section to go to a Woodsmen's competition, record axe work, and generate a sound-sampler to use in the performance.  If I were a conductor, which I'm not.

PS- what's wrong with being a Mahler fanboi?